# Play Movie with 2 languages simultaneously

Tags: windows, audio, sound-card, matroska

I know that a similiar question has been asked on how to achieve this in Linux. However this Question was asked 5 years ago and maybe there is a more convenient way to do this. Furthermore, if possible I would like to achieve this in Windows.

I would like to watch a MKV file where one audio track is routed to the headphones while the other is routed to the hdmi output. Can this be done in a manner which keeps the Picture and both soundtracks synchronized when the video is paused?

I do not have an external sound card.

EDIT: This is the old question: [How to play a movie listening to two sound tracks simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/1064686/how-to-play-a-movie-listening-to-two-sound-tracks-simultaneously)
What I archieved: I downloaded Voicemeter and I was able to route the Sound to 2 different outputs. But I could not route 2 different tracks to 2 different outputs.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Link to the earlier question would be useful, plus what your research has shown so far.

Comment: @Tetsujin done.

Comment: Which player are you using? VLC?

Comment: @MMM preferably yes, however I am comfortable to switch if there is a better alternative for this scenario.

Comment: Bilingual movies usually have different languages in left & right on a single audio track. This enables simple routing. I've never come across a player than can play two tracks simultaneously. Routing would be an additional issue as you'd need the video player to have 2 distinct 'audio outputs' even if these were virtual. I've never seen one that can do this. It's not impossible - just unlikely anyone has ever needed it enough to code it.